# Unable to store the same random string in cookies as in the variable

Tags: php, variables, cookies, random, setcookie

I am trying to store a randomly generated alphanumeric string into a cookie but the value set in the cookie is different from the variable. I would like to know how to store the same value in both the variable and the cookie.

*Function to generate the random string*

```
function str_random($len) {
   $result = "";
   $char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
   $array = str_split($char);
   for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) {
     $randchar = $array[array_rand($array)]; 
     $result .= $randchar;
   }
   return $result;
 }
```

*Storing random string in the cookie*

```
$remember_token = str_random(250);
$dbh->update("users", array(":remember_token" => $remember_token, ), array(":id" => $user[0]["id"]));
setcookie("remember", $remember_token, time() + 60*60*24*7);
```

Now, if I try to make a `var_dump` of the cookie value and the value stored in the database (or the variable), it will return me two different string:

```
$result = $dbh->find_where("users", array(":id" => $user[0]["id"]));
var_dump($_COOKIE['remember']);
var_dump($remember_token);
var_dump($result[0]['remember_token']);
```

> "Z0PuJEfjZFy87SDJiw2g6Yj1YrRL1xHQ9MDjr53h6OojzauagoRZinuGocxIrtPwQaZkSqyVOtfxBi0WF9VgFvTZIARCSZLyLACvmzCioFnTUtqt0r4vm33XKxcBpqFaWT1HAsKiQiuYVyDXwP9S7Y2VVxMyDxtQ3420MFM9OGmwprtDmYTnEpZ5U9vXl0QpMuLFdPw994OZcOjeg85bj9JUaYyGsTAjQZiEBULay3nPmyssKGQWJlEEtO" string(250) `//for the second line`
>
> "J2D1X5GnWgE2T9UX4KtoRque8cqdRaiFifvj5E2r9qNlQoZOLHacatLNKJtIAg1oE51d2Jg8qr14h1a0qK8CjMymk97o23qVVbCcgh3GOPAqJlfU8TXiSZi5cvXmyD2FhXPKZDo2VqwM07GZNaP1JnTnhIcMEEFlLY4XU2JGrGDU66rnv1DuOBWWkwdQlBdzgd4Sbi6laUbNDqIg49s3xRc30su1aS6riZFGPHAlOYWVaLpNnMHBs515o1" `//for both the third line and the fourth line`

If I had set the variable `$random_token` to a fixed string say `foobar`, the cookie would store the same value as the database would:

```
$remember_token = "foobar";
$$dbh->update("users", array(":remember_token" => $remember_token, ), array(":id" => $user[0]["id"]));
setcookie("remember", $remember_token, time() + 60*60*24*7);
var_dump($remember_token);
var_dump($_COOKIE["remember"]);
```

Output:

> string(6) "foobar"
>
> string(6) "foobar"

I suspect the problem being with the `str_random` function, generating a different token for the cookie than the one entered in the database. However, I do not know how to fix it.

For more information, here is the code for the method `find_where` and `update`:

```
public function find_where($tablename, $array) {
    $req = "SELECT * FROM ". $tablename. " WHERE ". str_replace(":", "", key($array)). "=".key($array);
    $smt = $this->conn->prepare($req);
    $smt->execute($array);
    $result = $smt->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}

public function update($tablename, $update, $param) {
    $keys_and_values =$this->format_keys_and_values($update);
    $req = "UPDATE ". $tablename. " SET ". $keys_and_values. " WHERE ". str_replace(":", "", key($param)). "=". key($param);
    $smt = $this->conn->prepare($req);
    $execute = array_merge($update, $param);
    $smt->execute($execute);
}
```

The code functions well generally (if I use those functions for another purpose, it would work)

Comment: I think this is a case of $_COOKIE being populated upon the request (from the client).  So you have the last value of the cookie set.  Not the new.  If you adjust your second example (the foobar one) to include say the time appended to the value, you may see different results.

Comment: @Progrock Then, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Think of $_COOKIE as a read only, populated at the beginning of your script.  You'll then adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: So in short, you are storing the same value in the database and the cookie, it's just that you can't access that value from $_COOKIE, until your next request.